# Create a variable in a superclass, but don't overwrite inheritor's setting

Tags: python, inheritance

I'd like to have a superclass that, as part of it's interface, provides a variable (or a getter function), and allows (but *does not require*) an inheritor to set this value. As follows:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = DEFAULT_VALUE

    def value(self):
        return self._value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        #note this class does not care about setting value
        super.__init__()
```

However, super's init will overwrite any custom setting done by B. If I don't set it in the superclass, and then a subclass does not want to implement it, anything that uses that variable will fail.

How do I create this variable in the superclass without overwriting what a subclass may want to set it to?

Comment: Why not just swap the two statements in `B.__init__` so you set the value _after_ calling `super.__init__`?

Comment: Doesn't `super.__init__` _have_ to be the last thing in a subclass' init?

Comment: Nope, you can place it at the top, in the middle, at the bottom or omit it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can simply do your subclass-specific initialization *after* calling `super().__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
        # time to overwrite that default value
        self._value = value
```

You can also just *not* call `super().__init__` if not necessary:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        if value is None:
            # fallback to default
            super().__init__()
        else:
            # otherwise set value from caller
            self._value = value

b = B()
print(b.value()) # prints the default value

b = B("overridden value")
print(b.value()) # prints "overridden value"
```

Comment: I don't know if any more clarity is needed, but to make it explicit, you can do initialization before and after the super init.

Comment: @tdelaney Good point, I've added an example that calls the super class initializer _conditionally_, hopefully that makes it clear it isn't required in any specific place.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Updated according to Simon Hawe's comment

You could do something like this:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value=DEFAULT_VALUE):
        self._value = value

    def value(self):
        return self._value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
```

Now `_value` will only be the default value if a subclass did not provide a value to the `super().__init__()` call.

Comment: Or instead of a default None you can use def __init__(self, value=DEFAULT_VALUE), which would allow you to set it to None if needed and reads nicer

Comment: @SimonHawe that's a lot better actually, don't know why I didn't think of that. I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: While this is a better solution (and the one I'm actually going to use), I've accepted the other answer because it answers the question exactly as asked